# Why does this regular expression only capture one word?

Tags: php, regex, unix, preg-replace

I'm trying to learn Regular Expressions. I know the basics, and I'm not terrible at regex, I'm just no pro - hence I've got a question for you guys. If you know regex, I bet it'll be simple.

What I've got currently is this:

```
/(\w+)\s-{1}\s(\w+)\.{1}(\w{3,4})/
```

What I'm trying to do is create a little script for myself that tidies up my music collection by formatting all of the filenames. I know there's other stuff out there already but this is a learning experience for me. I already screwed up all the titles once by replacing things like "Hell Aint A Bad Place To Be" with "Hell Aint a Bad Place To Be". In my wisdom I somehow ended up with "Hell Aint a ad Place to be" (I was looking a A followed by a space and an uppercase character). Obviously that was a nightmare to fix and it had to be done manually. Needless to say I'm testing samples first now.

Anyway, the above regex is sort of a stage 1 of many. Eventually I want to build it up, but for now I just need to get the simple bits working.

In the end I'd like to turn:

```
"arctic Monkeys- a fake tales of a san francisco"
```

into

```
"Arctic Monkeys - A Fake Tales of a San Francisco"
```

I know I'll need lookbehind assertions to grab when you're after a '-', because if the first word is 'a', 'of' etc. which I'd normally lowercase, I need to uppercase them (the above is a bad example for this use case I know).

Any way of fixing the existing regular expression would be great, and and **tips** on where to look on my cheatsheet to finish the rest off would be great (I'm not looking for a fully-fledged answer, since I need to learn to do it myself, I just can't figure why w+ is only getting one word).

Comment: I dont' know about the regex, but it may be a good idea to make a copy to experiment on. ;)

Comment: It's kinda hard to figure out what you want, especially when you go and explain all about the project, and then finishing with that you just want tips.. I'm not really sure that's a thing you can easily get here, as it is all "real answers" etc on SO. If you just want the answer to the basics and just tips on that `w+` thing, maybe focus on that :D. Anyway, I fixed your formatting: you needed an extra newline. You can use the interface `{}` button on a piece of selected text to have some help next time :D

Comment: You are going to need to do more than just regex ti get the first A capitalized and the second lowercase.  Explode based on '-' then do the different strings.

Comment: Well, I'm not a regex-pro but when you trying something allways to it on a little amount XD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe there is a much simpler way of approaching this problem: split the string into words, based on a much simpler regex, and then apply whatever processing you want to those words. This will allow you to perform more complicated transformations on the text in a much cleaner way. Here's an example:

```
<?php

$song = "arctic Monkeys- a fake tales of a san francisco";

// Split on spaces or - (the - is still present
// because it's only a lookahead match)
$words = preg_split("/([\s]+|(?=-))/", $song);

/*
Output for print_r:
Array
(
    [0] => arctic
    [1] => Monkeys
    [2] => -
    [3] => a
    [4] => fake
    [5] => tales
    [6] => of
    [7] => a
    [8] => san
    [9] => francisco
)
*/
print_r($words);

$new_words = array();
foreach ($words as $k => $word) {
        $new_words[] = processWord($word, $k, $words);
}

// This will output:
// Arctic Monkeys - A Fake Tales of a San Francisco
echo implode(' ', $new_words);

// You can add as many processing rules you want in here - in a very clean way
function processWord($word, $idx, $words) {
        if ($words[$idx - 1] == '-') return ucfirst($word);
        return strlen($word) > 2 ? ucfirst($word) : $word;
}
```

Here's an example of this code running: http://codepad.org/t6pc8WpR

Comment: +1 for not taking regexp all the way. I would even go as far to create an adaptable/flexible design for this. Splitting up the filenames is certainly the right place to start in my opinion.

Comment: True, good point! I'd gotten too carried away with trying to be clever with regex and overlooked the possibility of using something much simpler! Plus, not using a sample instead of using my actual music collection was... well, stupid to say the least :D. But, that you very much for your answer - this is certainly the smarter way to look at it!

Answer (score 1):

\w does not contain the blank. A working regex might be:

```
/^(.+?)\s*-\s*(.+)$/
```

Explanation:

```
^     - must start at the beginning of the string
(.+?) - match any character, be ungreedy
\s*   - match any number whitespace that might exists (including none)
-     - match character
\s*   - any whitespace again
(.+)  - remaining characters
$     - end of string
```

The transcoding would then happen in another replacing regex.

Comment: Good example, but I think you mean "non-greedy" with (.+?) :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm a little confused about what you're doing, but maybe this will help.  Remember that + is 1 or more characters, * is 0 or more.  So you probably want to do something like ([\s]*) to match spaces.  You don't need to specify the {1} next to a single character.

So maybe something like this:

```
([\w\s]+)([\s]*)-([\s]*)([\w\s]+)\.([\w]{3,4})
```

I haven't tested this code, but I think you get the idea.

Answer (score 0):

For the first part, \w doesn't match words, it matches word characters. It's equivalent to [A-Za-z0-9_].

Instead, try ([A-Za-z0-9_ ]+) as your first bit (has an extra space inside the match square brackets and removed the \s.

Comment: Note: `[A-Za-z0-9_ ]` (or `\w`) for that matter will not match umlaut characters, like ê or ö. `\S` or `.` will be more helpful here.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I have:

```
<?php
/**
 * Formats a string into a title:
 * * Pads all dashes with spaces.
 * * Uppercase all words with 3 letters or more.
 * * Uppercase first word and first words after dashes.
 *
 * @param $str
 *
 * @return string
 */
function format_title($str) {
    //Remove all spaces before and after dashes.
    //(These will return in the final product)
    $str = preg_replace("/\s?-\s?/", "-", $str);

    //Explode by dash.
    $string_split_by_dash = explode("-", $str);
    //For each sentence (separated by dashes)
    foreach ($string_split_by_dash as &$sentence) {
        //Uppercase all words.
        $sentence = ucwords($sentence);
        //Explode into words (by space)
        $words = explode(" ", $sentence);
        //For each word
        foreach ($words as &$word) {
            //If its length is smaller than 3
            if (strlen($word) < 3) {
                //Lowercase it.
                $word = strtolower($word);
            }
        }
        //Implode back into a sentence.
        $sentence = implode(" ", $words);
        //Uppercase the first word, regardless of length.
        $sentence = ucfirst($sentence);
    }

    //Implode all sentances back by space-padded dash.
    $str = implode(" - ", $string_split_by_dash);

    return $str;
}

$str = "arctic Monkeys- a fake tales of a san francisco";
var_dump(format_title($str));
```

I'd argue it's more readable (and more documentable) than a regex. Probably more efficient too, (didn't check).